# How to use NOT LIKE and JOIN together in mysql?

Tags: mysql, join, sql-like

I need to exclude from query some records, where day name isset in exclude value 'excl_days'.

Simple function is working:

```
SELECT post_id, start, end, excl_days FROM `mytable_events` 
WHERE `excl_days` NOT LIKE '%".$today_name."%' 
ORDER BY DATE(start) DESC
```

But with JOIN and GROUP i have empty result after adding NOT LIKE. Without NOT LIKE all is working fine.

```
SELECT o1.post_id, o1.start, o1.end, o1.excl_days 
FROM `mytable_events` o1 
JOIN `mytable_posts` o2 ON o1.post_id = o2.ID 
WHERE `o1.excl_days` NOT LIKE '%".$today_name."%'
GROUP BY o1.post_id ORDER BY DATE(o1.start) DESC
```

Full query is:

```
SELECT o1.post_id, o1.start, o1.end, o1.excl_days 
FROM `mytable_events` o1 
JOIN `mytable_posts` o2 ON o1.post_id = o2.ID 
WHERE DATE(o1.start) <= '".$today."' AND DATE(o1.end) >= '".$today."'
AND o2.post_type = 'events' AND o2.post_status = 'publish' 
AND `o1.excl_days` NOT LIKE '%".$today_name."%'
GROUP BY o1.post_id ORDER BY DATE(o1.start) DESC
```

How make this to work? Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
  SELECT o1.post_id, o1.start, o1.end, o1.excl_days 
  FROM `mytable_events` o1 
  JOIN `mytable_posts` o2 ON (o1.post_id = o2.ID 
  AND o1.excl_days NOT LIKE '%".$today_name."%')
  GROUP BY o1.post_id ORDER BY DATE(o1.start) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try getting rid of the back ticks in your where clause.  They are unnecessary and not correctly formed.

```
SELECT o1.post_id, o1.start, o1.end, o1.excl_days 
FROM `honchar_events` o1 
JOIN `honchar_posts` o2 ON o1.post_id = o2.ID 
WHERE o1.excl_days NOT LIKE '%".$today_name."%'
GROUP BY o1.post_id ORDER BY DATE(o1.start) DESC
```